# sum duplicate rows value using datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, sum, duplicates, row

i have DataTable which can have duplicate rows. In the picture highlighted columns have all the same values. I would need to identify those rows and sum the salary( in original table is "jamekol").

[image]

and i want to sum all duplicate Name's salary value like this :

[image]

here is my orginal table :
[image]
 Note : i need all columns .  Can anyone suggest how to do that?

```
DataTable new_Table = new DataTable();
                new_Table.Columns.Add("radif");
                new_Table.Columns.Add("sh_factor");
                new_Table.Columns.Add("t_factor");
                new_Table.Columns.Add("Taraf");
                new_Table.Columns.Add("m_taraf");
                new_Table.Columns.Add("mantaghe");
                new_Table.Columns.Add("jam");
                new_Table.Columns.Add("jamekol");
                new_Table.Columns.Add("m_kartkhan");
                new_Table.Columns.Add("m_takhfif");
                new_Table.Columns.Add("n_karbar");
                new_Table.Columns.Add("sh_sanad");
                new_Table.Columns.Add("code");
                new_Table.Columns.Add("m_tasvie");
                new_Table.Columns.Add("m_porsant");
                new_Table.Columns.Add("d_takhfif");
                new_Table.Columns.Add("m_maliat");
                new_Table.Columns.Add("m_avarez");
                new_Table.Columns.Add("n_taraf");
                new_Table.Columns.Add("v_moravede");
                var groupedByState = dt.AsEnumerable()
                    .GroupBy(r => r.Field<String>("Taraf"));
                foreach (var group in groupedByState)
                {
                    DataRow maxPremRow = group.OrderByDescending(r => r.Field<String>("Taraf")).First();
                    DataRow newRow = new_Table.Rows.Add();

                    newRow.SetField("id_po", group.Key);
                    newRow.SetField("Status", maxPremRow.Field<string>("Status"));
                    newRow.SetField("Cost_ex", group.Sum(r => r.Field<double?>("Cost_ex")));

                    newRow.SetField("Taraf", maxPremRow.Field<string>("Taraf"));
                    newRow.SetField("jamekol", group.Sum(r => r.Field<double?>("Cost_ex")));
                    newRow.SetField("radif", maxPremRow.Field<string>("radif"));
                    newRow.SetField("sh_factor", maxPremRow.Field<string>("sh_factor"));
                    newRow.SetField("t_factor", maxPremRow.Field<string>("t_factor"));
                    newRow.SetField("m_taraf", maxPremRow.Field<string>("m_taraf"));
                    newRow.SetField("mantaghe", maxPremRow.Field<string>("mantaghe"));
                    newRow.SetField("jam", maxPremRow.Field<string>("jam"));
                    newRow.SetField("m_kartkhan", maxPremRow.Field<string>("m_kartkhan"));
                    newRow.SetField("m_takhfif", maxPremRow.Field<string>("m_takhfif"));
                    newRow.SetField("n_karbar", maxPremRow.Field<string>("n_karbar"));
                    newRow.SetField("sh_sanad", maxPremRow.Field<string>("sh_sanad"));
                    newRow.SetField("code", maxPremRow.Field<string>("code"));
                    newRow.SetField("m_tasvie", maxPremRow.Field<string>("m_tasvie"));
                    newRow.SetField("m_porsant", maxPremRow.Field<string>("m_porsant"));
                    newRow.SetField("d_takhfif", maxPremRow.Field<string>("d_takhfif"));
                    newRow.SetField("m_maliat", maxPremRow.Field<string>("m_maliat"));
                    newRow.SetField("m_avarez", maxPremRow.Field<string>("m_avarez"));
                    newRow.SetField("n_taraf", maxPremRow.Field<string>("n_taraf"));
                    newRow.SetField("v_moravede", maxPremRow.Field<string>("v_moravede"));                       

                }
                radGridView3.DataSource = new_Table;
```

Comment: You need to learn about sum and group by in SQL. Use that knowledge in solving problem and post a question here is you face any problem in that. https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/sum-with-group-by.php

Answer (score 0):

```
           var query = from uu in dt.AsEnumerable()
                     select new
                    {
                        radif = uu.Field<string>("radif"),
                        sh_factor = uu.Field<string>("sh_factor"),
                        t_factor = uu.Field<string>("t_factor"),
                        Taraf = uu.Field<string>("Taraf"),
                        m_taraf = uu.Field<string>("m_taraf"),
                        mantaghe = uu.Field<string>("mantaghe"),
                        jam = uu.Field<string>("jam"),
                        jamekol = uu.Field<string>("jamekol"),
                        m_kartkhan = uu.Field<string>("m_kartkhan"),
                        m_takhfif = uu.Field<string>("m_takhfif"),
                        n_karbar = uu.Field<string>("n_karbar"),
                        sh_sanad = uu.Field<string>("sh_sanad"),
                        code = uu.Field<string>("code"),
                        m_tasvie = uu.Field<string>("m_tasvie"),
                        m_porsant = uu.Field<string>("m_porsant"),
                        d_takhfif = uu.Field<string>("d_takhfif"),
                        m_maliat = uu.Field<string>("m_maliat"),
                        m_avarez = uu.Field<string>("m_avarez"),
                        n_taraf = uu.Field<string>("n_taraf"),
                        v_moravede = uu.Field<string>("v_moravede"),
                    };
                    
 var groupedByState = query.GroupBy(cc => cc.Taraf).Select(dd => new
        {
                v_moravede = dd.Select(ee => ee.sh_factor).First(),
                n_taraf = dd.Select(ee => ee.sh_factor).First(),
                m_avarez = dd.Select(ee => ee.sh_factor).First(),
                m_maliat = dd.Select(ee => ee.sh_factor).First(),
                d_takhfif = dd.Select(ee => ee.sh_factor).First(),
                m_porsant = dd.Select(ee => ee.sh_factor).First(),
                m_tasvie = dd.Select(ee => ee.sh_factor).First(),
                code = dd.Select(ee => ee.sh_factor).First(),
                sh_sanad = dd.Select(ee => ee.sh_factor).First(),
                n_karbar = dd.Select(ee => ee.sh_factor).First(),
                m_takhfif = dd.Select(ee => ee.sh_factor).First(),
                m_kartkhan = dd.Select(ee => ee.sh_factor).First(),
                jamekol = dd.Sum(ee => Convert.ToDecimal(ee.jamekol.ToString())),
                jam = dd.Select(ee => ee.sh_factor).First(),
                mantaghe = dd.Select(ee => ee.sh_factor).First(),
                m_taraf = dd.Select(ee => ee.sh_factor).First(),
                Taraf = dd.Key,
                t_factor = dd.Select(ee => ee.sh_factor).First(),
                sh_factor = dd.Select(ee => ee.sh_factor).First(),
                radif = dd.Select(ee => ee.sh_factor).First(),
                                        
        });
        
    radGridView3.DataSource = groupedByState.ToList();
```

Comment: Please see the above implementation, although the above code can be simplified by combining into one chunk, this 2 chunks approach has an advantage with the manipulation of data, which is more applicable to the real world problems

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Ive basically grouped the rows from the old datatable that had matching names and then summed the salarys and then created a new datatable with the new groupings.

```
DataTable new_Table = new DataTable();
        new_Table.Columns.Add("Name");
        new_Table.Columns.Add("Salary");
        new_Table.Columns.Add("Date");
        new_Table.Columns.Add("Description");

        var groupedByState = old_datatable.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(r => r.Field<String>("Name"));
        foreach (var group in groupedByState)
        {
            DataRow maxPremRow = group.OrderByDescending(r => r.Field<String>("Name")).First();
            DataRow newRow = new_Table.Rows.Add();


            newRow.SetField("Name", maxPremRow.Field<string>("Name"));
            newRow.SetField("Salary", group.Sum(r => r.Field<double?>("Salary")));
            newRow.SetField("Description", maxPremRow.Field<string>("Description"));
            newRow.SetField("Date", maxPremRow.Field<string>("Date"));


        }
```

If there is an issue with the code could you show me the related code you have and i will implement it into it for you. :)

Can you let me know how you go?